# Storing Image in WebApplication Folder

Tags: java

I am sending image to a Servlet using html form. I am getting only filename but wants the full path of the image. Second, i want to store this image in web application images folder.

Comment: why do you want to have full path? no point to get the full path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting only filename but wants the full path of the image

For security reasons it is impossible to get the full path to the image on the client computer. This information is never sent to the server.

As far as the second part of your question is concerned about storing the uploaded image on the server, there are [many articles](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) out there illustrating this.